# Passing _POST variable to Mysql WHERE clause

Tags: php, mysql, variables

```
<?php
//Connect to DB
$dbcnx = @mysql_connect("$db_host", $db_user, "$db_password");
if (!$dbcnx) {
 echo( "<P>Unable to connect to the " .
    "database server at this time.</P>" );
 exit();
}
mysql_select_db("daily_audit", $dbcnx);
// Request the text of all the hosts
if(!empty($_POST['checklist'])) {
    foreach($_POST['checklist'] as $check) {
        $result = mysql_query(
           "DELETE FROM hosts_list WHERE IP_Address = %s ", $check);
if (!$result) {
 echo("<P>Error performing query: " .
     mysql_error() . "</P>");
 exit();
}
    }
}
?>
```

I am having an issue getting the following code to run. I have confirmed that the _POST variable contains data but I am pretty sure that there is an issue with how my SQL query is being process. Sorry I am a PHP n00b and I am trying to understand how I can correct this issue. I know that the query will likely require ' ' around the IP address which is making this tricky. Thanks all in advance.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysql_query()` can't format your query like that.

You're probably looking for [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/sprintf):

```
$result = mysql_query(
    sprintf("DELETE FROM hosts_list WHERE IP_Address = %s ", $check) );
```

Note that your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should always sanitize user input before using it in a database query. Better yet,  switch to MySQLi / PDO and use prepared statements.

Comment: Thank you for your help. This makes sense and I will look into the two libraries you mentioned. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

The `mysql_query` function cannot format a string.

You were probably thinking of `sprintf()`:

```
$query = sprintf("DELETE FROM hosts_list
                  WHERE IP_Address = %s", mysql_real_escape_string($check));
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Consider switching to [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php), because the mysql extension is now deprecated.